# Как добавить ListView во Fragment Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть фрагмент с таким кодом

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(com.example.tabv3.R.layout.fragment_2, container, false)
    val ListName = arrayOf("Дальневосточная","Малоазитская","Озерная","Остромордая","Прудовая","Сибирская")
    val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(this.requireContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ListName)
    val lv = view.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list)
    lv.adapter=arrayAdapter

    return inflater.inflate(com.example.tabv3.R.layout.fragment_2, container, false)
}
```

Приложение просто вылетает, когда я убираю строку `lv.adapter=arrayAdapter` приложение не вылетает, но контент не показывает конечно. Как написать правильно?

Вот разметка

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/teal_200"
    tools:context=".Fragment2">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"></ListView>
   </FrameLayout>
```

Логи
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По коду вроде всё верно, только вернуть нужно созданную и настроенную вью, а не инфлейтить ещё одну чистую: `return view`. Насчёт падения: проверьте макет `fragment_2.xml` - его ли вообще вы хотите показать и есть ли в нём элемент `ListView` с `android:id="@+id/list"`. Если всё на месте, как вам кажется - добавьте в вопрос лог падения и код разметки

Comment: Дело в адаптере, то есть я не могу его присвоить listView.  Я попробовала создать таким же методом listView в обычном окне - тоже все упало, хотя вроде делаю по инструкции

Comment: У вас `com.example.tabv3.R.layout.fragment_2` указан с пакетом, а `R.id.list` вероятно ошибочно импортирован из другого пакета (не вашего) - это может быть причиной не нахождения элемента в разметке. Проверьте импорт класса `R` и исправьте у него пакет на свой вот так: `import com.example.tabv3.R`

Comment: Да, спасибо, заработало!